# PHP DOMDocument remove tag attribute

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm having a problem removing attributes from the HTML tags

```
    $content = '<span lang="en" xml:lang="en">test</span>';

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
    $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

    foreach($nodes as $node)
    {
        if ($node->hasAttribute('lang'))
        {
            $node->removeAttribute('lang');
        }

        if ($node->hasAttribute('xml:lang'))
        {
            $node->removeAttribute('xml:lang');
        }
    }

    echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
```

But the result keeps coming

```
    <span xml:lang="en">test</span>
```

Why only removes the `lang` attribute and don't remove the `xml:lang="en"`? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `xml:lang="en"` is not corrected value of attribute in html. Change these lines:

```
$dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
//code...
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
```

to

```
$dom->loadXML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
//code...
echo $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```